# HDD and SSD addressing

Tags: memory-management

I have a doubt about HDD and SSD addressing. Could someone explain me what is the minimum addressable unity for HDD and SSD?
In the case of RAM, we can address the single byte. But I presume that HDD and SSD have a a different behavior.
Thank you

Comment: https://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/manual/Interface%20manuals/100293068j.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is all about physics.

On an SSD drive you can read blocks, usually 4K, in constant time. You can set non-zero bits in a block in constant time. And you can set a larger block, often 128 or 256 Kbyte, to all bits zero. That means, to modify a block, you either need to know that it is all bits zero, or find a new location for the block in a zeroed area, or erase a larger block first.

On a hard drive, you can read or write a complete sector. The time needed depends on how long it takes for the physical sector to appear under the read head. To make access faster, the firmware of the drive will cache blocks in RAM, start reading a track once it is under the read head in case the data is used later, and cache data to be written to combine multiple writes if possible.

There's a new technology called "shingled drives", where you gain data density, but only can write in places where the next inner track is not used, because a write operation writes over the inner track. This is fine when you write gigabytes of consecutive data, but not when you constantly modify single blocks.

Answer (score 0):

An operating system can address and access any external storage (like HDD or SSD) at the individual byte level - such way is usually called a [Raw Disk](http://www.linfo.org/raw_disk.html). However, the actual reading and writing data at the **hardware** level normally happens in [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)).

Each RAM data byte passes through many software and hardware **levels** before it's stored on the magnetic surface (or anywhere else), and these levels may differ for different operating systems and hardware - so it's impossible to talk about general behavior of HDD and SSD without clearly defining this abstraction level.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Only one thing: in the case of HDD the block size must be a multiple of the sector size?

Comment: @Bender - Basically, yes. One more reference for you: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Blocks,_block_devices_and_block_sizes

Comment: Thank you again